# invalid literal for int() with base 10: - foreignkey

Tags: python, django

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'revision.user.id'

```
 user_profile = articleread.objects.filter(user_id=request.POST.get("name"), article_id=str(request.POST.get("article"))).order_by('-id')[0]
```

as error too

```
user_profile = articleread.objects.filter(user_id=int(request.POST.get("name")), article_id=str(request.POST.get("article"))).order_by('-id')[0] 


   <input name="percent" id="percent" size="4" type="text" form="my_form" />    

   <input name="name" id="name" type="hidden" value=revision.user.id form="my_form" />

   <input name="article" id="article" type="hidden" value=article.id form="my_form" /></td>
```

```
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/ form="my_form"></td>
```

In models db both field are foreign key:

```
   db.create_table(u'wiki_articleread', (
        (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
        ('current_revision', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField')(blank=True, related_name=u'current_set', unique=True, null=True, to=orm['wiki.ArticleRevision'])),
        ('readed', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)),
        ('last', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now=True, blank=True)),
        ('user', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(blank=True, related_name=u'user_articles', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, to=orm['auth.User'])),
        ('paid', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=False)),
        ('read', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=True)),
        ('article', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(to=orm['wiki.Article'])),
        ('percent', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.FloatField')(default='0')),
    ))
```

Comment: `request.POST.get("name")` I suppose that one refers to a string and not to a user id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out the curly braces when including variables in your template. For example, instead of

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="hidden" value=revision.user.id form="my_form" />
```

you should have

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="hidden" value={{ revision.user.id }} form="my_form" />
```

You might want to explore using [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/). They have several useful features including automatic generation of the html.